# C# Reflection Programmatic Event Handlers with Custom Event Args

Tags: c#, events, reflection

Here is my problem/scenario

```
public class TestEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<TestEventArgs> TestClick
```

How can I attach an EventHandler on TestClick by using reflection? (obj is instance, Activator.CreateInstance)

```
EventInfo eventClick = obj.GetType().GetEvent("TestClick");
Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventClick.EventHandlerType, obj, ????);
eventClick.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
```

My problem being that TestEventArgs is declared in an external dll, but ???? methodinfo above requires the signature in its delegate?

Comment: If you plan to raise event with TestEventArgs you will need to reference it somehow. By referencing external assembly or by loading it dynamically. Please provide more info about what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: This is what I want to achieve, but the EventArgs can be dynamic. MethodInfo methodOn_Click = this.GetType().GetMethod("On_Click"); public void On_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Test 1 2 3");
} How would you suggest to dynamically load it? Is there a way in reflection to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

I manage to get my code to work by following the technique describe by the following article,
http://www.pelennorfields.com/matt/2009/03/13/createdelegate-error-binding-to-target-method/

In essence, if I do the following, I get the error, "Error binding to target method",

**FAIL:**

```
EventInfo eventClick = obj.GetType().GetEvent("TestClick");
Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    eventClick.EventHandlerType, this, "TestClick");
eventClick.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
```

**SUCCESS:**

But when I changed it to:

```
MethodInfo methodOn_TestClick = this.GetType().GetMethod("TestClick", new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(EventArgs));

Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    event_DomClick.EventHandlerType, this, methodOn_TestClick, true); // note the change here

eventClick.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
```

I then used reflection in my TestClick method, to get the properties I needed out of the standard EventArgs.

eg.

```
public void TestClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PropertyInfo prop_ID = e.GetType().GetProperty("ID");

    int id = Convert.toInt32(prop_ID.GetValue(e, null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you control the source of the target assembly? If so, simply add the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx) assembly attribute to the target assembly.

Answer (score -2):

If you used `Activator.CreateInstance()` you've got a reference to the type of your object right?

**To add your own handler:**

Call `type.GetFields()` on it, now you've got the internal fields (if the event is defined in a base class you need to first walk up the heirachy using `type.BaseType` to go up a level to you get to the level you need).

Once you have a `FieldInfo` instance for the delegate backing the event handler call `GetValue()` on the `FieldInfo` instance passing your object in. Now you've got the delegate backing the event handler. Now call `FieldInfo.SetValue(myObject, Delegate.Combine(currentValue, myHandler))`.

I'm pretty sure that with Delegate.Combine you just have to make sure the signature of your event handler matches, but not the actual type. So it should be enough to create your own delegate with the same signature.

Comment: An event doesn't have to have a backing delegate field. And even if it does, its non-trivial to find the right field for the event you're working with.

Comment: Sure, but *something* has to back it (well, it could back itself of course).

In his scenario he's got no other option than reflection (or modifing the code of the other assembly if he can). He's already gone down the rabbit hole by using Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate the class the event exists on, and yes this is a britle solution but he doesn't really have many options here if he doesn't control the source of the target assembly and really needs to do this. I never said it was non-trival, but the debugger Watch window is your friend...